# Right-angle mark not drawn correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a right triangle △*ABC* with its right angle at *C*, and the altitude drawn to the hypotenuse.  I have code that should draw two right-angle marks at *C* and at the foot of the altitude.  The similar commands display slightly different right-angle marks.  The one at the foot of the altitude is correct.  The one at *C* is not perpendicular to side *BC*.  I have drawn a green line segment to illustrate this.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%A right triangle is drawn.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) ({(1/4)*16},0) coordinate (B) ({(1/4)*12},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(3))}) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The vertices are labeled.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!5mm!45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) -- (U) -- ($(B)!(U)!(C)$);
\draw[green] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (U) -- ($(U) +({\n1+180}:0.5)$);
\draw[fill=green] ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) circle (1pt);


%The foot of the altitude is labeled F.
\coordinate (F) at ({(1/4)*(12)},0);
\draw[dashed] (F) -- (C);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at F.
\coordinate (V) at ($(F)!3.25mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(V)!(B)$) -- (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(F)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Rmano  I appreciate you adding the diagram to my post.

Comment: Can't find the problem, so at least I tried to help ;-)

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek  Do you see the mistake in the code?

Comment: Related [Error in projection modifier with tikz calc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271476/error-in-projection-modifier-with-tikz-calc)

Comment: Another [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302409/perpendicular-lines-from-the-same-point-to-the-same-line-are-different) ?

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by Mark Wibrow in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256377/9335) the definition of `\pgfpointnormalised` can be corrected to obtain better precision.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, spy}

% use the Mark Wibrow's correction
\makeatletter
\def\pgfpointnormalised#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \pgfmathatantwo{\the\pgf@y}{\the\pgf@x}%
  \let\pgf@tmp=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathcos@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
  \pgfmathsin@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=17mm, connect spies}]

%A right triangle is drawn.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) ({(1/4)*16},0) coordinate (B) ({(1/4)*12},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(3))}) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The vertices are labeled.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!5mm!45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) -- (U) -- ($(B)!(U)!(C)$);
\draw[green] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (U) -- ($(U) +({\n1+180}:0.5)$);
\draw[fill=green] ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) circle (1pt);


%The foot of the altitude is labeled F.
\coordinate (F) at ({(1/4)*(12)},0);
\draw[dashed] (F) -- (C);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at F.
\coordinate (V) at ($(F)!3.25mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(V)!(B)$) -- (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(F)$);

\spy[red] on (2.7,1.5) in node at (1,1.7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will wait for a response to the " feature request" by Rokas.  I can issue commands to draw the right-angle mark that does not use the `calc` package.  Thanks for the web site.  Now I know that this is a flaw in `pgf`.

Comment: I will wait also! that error should be fixed as soon as possible, because projection modifiers are often used

Comment: This has been fixed upstream: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/65b8261c63c6f4adfca60106528e2d1bf1e2cb60/

Answer (score 5):

The calculation of projection involves `\pgfpointnormalised{⟨point⟩}`, which is documented as follows

> This command returns a normalised version of `⟨point⟩`, that is, a
>   vector of length 1pt pointing in the direction of `⟨point⟩`. If `⟨point⟩`
>   is the 0-vector or extremely short, a vector of length 1pt pointing
>   upwards is returned. This command is not implemented by calculating
>   the length of the vector, but rather by calculating the angle of the
>   vector and then using (something equivalent to) the `\pgfpointpolar`
>   command. This ensures that the point will really have length 1pt, but
>   it is not guaranteed that the vector will precisely point in the
>   direction of `⟨point⟩` due to the fact that the polar tables are
>   accurate only up to one degree. Normally, this is not a problem.

So this is not a precision issue but an algorithmic *feature*. In particular, including fpu-engine is not necessary helpful.

One can simply rewrite the calculation by redefining `\tikz@cc@after@project`, solving the issue once and for all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\makeatletter
\newdimen\pgf@xd
\newdimen\pgf@yd
\def\tikz@cc@after@project#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  % Ok, now we need to project (xc,yc) on the line (xb,xc) to (x,y)
  \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgf@yb%
  % Scalar product
  \pgf@xd=\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xc}\pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@xd by\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@yc}\pgf@y%
  \pgf@yd=\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}\pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@yd by\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}\pgf@y%
  \divide\pgf@xd by\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@yd}
  % and add
  \advance\pgf@xb by\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xd}\pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@yb by\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xd}\pgf@y%
  \tikz@cc@mid@checks%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%A right triangle is drawn.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) ({(1/4)*16},0) coordinate (B) ({(1/4)*12},{(1/4)*(4*sqrt(3))}) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The vertices are labeled.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

%A right-angle mark is drawn at C.
\coordinate (U) at ($(C)!5mm!45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) -- (U) -- ($(B)!(U)!(C)$);
\draw[green] let \p1=($(B)-(C)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (U) -- ($(U) +({\n1+180}:0.5)$);
\draw[fill=green] ($(A)!(U)!(C)$) circle (1pt);


%The foot of the altitude is labeled F.
\coordinate (F) at ({(1/4)*(12)},0);
\draw[dashed] (F) -- (C);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at F.
\coordinate (V) at ($(F)!3.25mm!-45:(A)$);
\draw ($(A)!(V)!(B)$) -- (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(F)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## P.S.

Package `tkz-euclide` implements orthogonal projection by calculating the intersection of two specific lines. This involves even more arithmetics and they are done by package `fp`.

After all, I guess it is still a good practice to fix the `calc` library instead of asking users to abandon it.

Comment: I have used such code to draw right-angle marks hundreds of times.  The lengths of the line segments are `3mm` or `3.5mm`.  This is the only time that the `calc` package did not compile the code correctly.

Comment: To draw the right-angle mark at C, I decided to avoid using the `calc` package.  See my comments to Martin.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I am glad to hear that. Because after all `calc` is nothing but **syntactic sugar**. And most of the time I rather do the calculation myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the order in coordinate calculation:

```
\draw ($(C)!(U)!(A)$) -- (U) -- ($(C)!(U)!(B)$);
```

I played around with your example and found this to work for me.
To be honest: I don't know why.

Comment: The `calc` package compiled the code correctly for drawing one right-angle mark but not the other.  That is odd.  To get the right-angle mark at `C` drawn correctly, I adapted the code suggested by Gonzalo Medina at "Error in projection modifier with tikz calc".

Comment: That code avoids use of the `calc` package.

Comment: `\draw ($(C)!3.25mm!(A)$) -- ($($(C)!3.25mm!(A)$)!5mm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (T) -- ($(T)!3.25mm!-90:($(C)!5mm!(A)$)$);`